# Nested seqs in clojure.spec

Tags: clojure.spec

When I use clojure.spec, I am trying to figure out how to spec nested seq/vector. Here is my failing example:

```
(s/def ::test (s/cat :s any? :r (s/cat :int int?)))
(s/explain-str ::test ["test" [1]])
;; => "[1] - failed: int? in: [1] at: [:r :int] spec: :ct.biz.ext2-test/test\n"
```

As you can see it fails on `[1]` being explained against `int?`. Why not against `(s/cat :int int?)`? It looks like it's actually flattening the spec, which was mentioned in some note somewhere. But how would I correctly spec  my data?

Answer (score 0):

`s/cat` is a regular expression. So it will match all expression that fit. `s/spec` allows to create a nested spec. So the correct spec for above is:

`(s/cat :any any? :r (s/spec (s/cat int int?)))`